# How to write to an existing .xlsm file through Perl

Tags: perl, xlsm

Could someone please clarify if there is any Perl package to edit a pre-existing .xlsm file?

I tried few examples posted in CPAN page and this site which use the combination of  WriteExcel and ParseExcel::SaveParser. They are not working for .xlsm file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to open an existing xlsm file using Excel::Writer::XLSX, as of version 0.72 Excel::Writer::XLSX, according to the page given by psxls (quote: "This module cannot, as yet, be used to write to an existing Excel XLSX file.").
A solution is to use Win32:OLE, it's well explained in this tutorial: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=153486. It tested it on my side, I was able to modify a pre-existing xlsm file.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.72/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm) should work for you. For getting started, you can check the related author's [blog post](http://blogs.perl.org/users/john_mcnamara/2012/12/adding-macros-to-excelwriterxlsx.html) and a related [Perl script example](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Examples.pm#Example%3a_macros.pl).

Comment: It doesn't seem to allow the macros to be edited though? They are extracted as a binary blob and included verbatim in the new Excel sheet, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right. It's not clear though if the OP wanted to edit the macros or not.